# I dont get why I cant get a json format with requests.Request()?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
from requests import Request as R

markets = R("GET", "https://ftx.com/api/markets")
print(markets.json())
```

Error:
print(markets.json())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1

I want to get the HTTP response as json but it doesnt work although it works with requests.get().
Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Request` is just the object that *represents* the request. You want `requests.request` to construct *and* make the request.

```
import requests

markets = requests.request("GET", "https://ftx.com/api/markets")
```

The `json` attribute of a `Request` object would be the JSON payload of the request, not the JSON response.

To make a request manually with a `Request` object, you need to first prepare it, then use a session to send the request. For example,

```
markets = requests.Request("GET", "https://ftx.com/api/markets")
r = markets.prepare()
s = requests.Session()
result = s.send(r)
print(result.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
example:

# import requests module
import requests
 
# Making a get request
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
 
# print response
print(response)
 
# print json content
print(response.json())
```